# Segmentation fault for Z3 SMT

Tags: java, z3

I am using Java API of Z3. While checking 'SATISFIABILITY' (s.status) i am getting segmentation fault. Can someone please help to debug this issue. Is there any way to dump message so that i can debug this problem. I tried using Log.open(), but it didnt seems to be of much help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Log.open()` must be called before any other interaction with Z3. Once enabled, it will produce a file called z3.log which we can replay without requiring access to your application/input/data/etc.

Neither `'SATISFIABILITY'` nor `s.status` are valid Z3/Java expressions, so I can't tell what exactly you are trying to do. If you believe any of this is due to a bug in Z3, please create a new issue in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues).